# Ron has Charlie’s old wand

Tags: harry-potter, ron-weasley

in The philosophers stone Ron says he has Charlie’s old wand.

Would it work for him properly. And why would Charlie want a new wand?

Answer (score 1):

We know from throughout this series that every wizard can use any wand, but some wands pair with the wizard best. This can be a benefit or curse to the user, as it's clear that although wands are unique in that they choose their user, the material the wand is made of is a deciding factor.

Although I do not have enough evidence off the top of my head to support this, people with ideal wands made of more 'common' material and build would theoretically have a better time finding and equivalent or better wand. On the other hand, people like, let's say, Harry Potter, have a very specific perfect wand (phoenix feathers don't grow on trees, and you don't find phoenixes just lying around everywhere), so aside from the Elder wand, no wand will truly be perfect for Harry. That being said, I'm sure he'll find something he can work with.

Another thing: wands that are attracted similar people have similar properties (again, don't remember where I remember this from - might be because Harry was a horcrux for most of his life in the books). Charlie and Ron are both Weasleys, with different ambitions but similar upbringing, which makes them similar people. And maybe Charlie found a better wand lol.

Also: Harry got himself killed by Voldemort, therefore destroying one of Voldy's horcruxes. Would that mean that the phoenix-feather wand he had wouldn't work too well anymore? Not sure - Harry broke his wand well before that, so I'm not sure if there's a way to be sure. Please let me know if I messed up.

Comment: Whilst you don’t have evidence for it yet it would be improved if you could edit some in.

Comment: Nice round up. Tbh I feel JK may have been so intent in making Ron sound poor she just rhymed off a few things and never really gave it a thought lol.

Comment: @Martin, out of universe, JKR probably hadn't yet come up with the idea of wands developing an affinity for their owners over time.  That didn't really become an important plot point until the very last book, IIRC.